# Can not edit object after failed Normal Map Bake

Tags: edit-mode, normals

Using Blender 2.79 I am attempting to create a ferret to animate.  The body has been created in two versions. Both low poly and high ply objects which are located in the same space.  The low poly has been UV unwrapped.  I was trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOYRCI-dtjU to bake a normal map of the high poly object to apply to the low poly version.  I selected the high poly and low poly objects, set up the bake controls as instructed and hit BAKE.  This came back with an error saying NO VALID SELECTED OBJECTS.  I went back and fiddled with various controls for a while with the same results before giving up for the night and closed Blender without saving.

When I opened it today to try again I found the hi poly version can not be opened in edit mode or seen in the 3Dview. Cycles Render shows it just fine.

Any ideas what might have gone wrong and how to get back into the hi poly model?

[image][image]

The file can be found at [WeTransfer](https://we.tl/t-o3UCgTLpMv)

Comment: perhaps share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Would share if I could.  At 62.9 MiB Stack-Exchange will not take it.

Comment: maybe here? http://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That has a 30 Mb limit also.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: then, wetransfer?

Comment: No valid selected objects usually means Selected To Active is or is not used when it should be, i.e if baking with it checked and selecting only one object or with it unchecked and selecting 2 objects. Hard to tell about what happens with highpoly there, at least some screenshots together with file uploaded to Google drive could help

Comment: Link to file and screenshots added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opened the file again and hit / in the number pad a couple times.  This was one of the first things I tried but for some reason this time it took.  The high res. object can be edited again and I was able to bake a Normal Map. The Normal Map pointed out some problems that need fixing but everything seems to be working again.